# execute a python file from pycharm console

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

I have a python file and I want to execute it from PyCharm console.

I'm in the directory of the project (where there is my file)

I tried to follow the solution in this thread: [Running a module from the pycharm console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874046/running-a-module-from-the-pycharm-console)

but I got the following error:

```
from project_main_folder import *
home_scorer_macro.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-20-24aaf6f313c6>", line 1, in <module>
    home_scorer_macro.py
NameError: name 'home_scorer_macro' is not defined
```

I tried directly without "import" to call execute the file, like:

```
python home_scorer_macro.py
```

but I got the following error as well:

```
File "<ipython-input-29-735c29c27d57>", line 1
    python home_scorer_macro.py
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Try it with the IPython magic command [%run](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run): `%run home_scorer_macro`.

Comment: @Xukrao , thanx, it works with run command. I was trying python, python3 etc. but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the console for the command prompt. The console allows you to type code and have it interpreted as you type line by line (or function by function). The command prompt allows you to say things like `python home_scorer_macro.py`. If you are trying to run the `home_scorer_macro` function from learning you can try:

```
from learning import home_scorer_macro
home_scorer_macro()
```

It is difficult to tell what you are trying to do without you providing any description of what you are trying to accomplish, though. You could also try something like

```
import os
os.system('"python home_scorer_macro.py"')
raw_input()
```

if you would like to combine commmand prompts and consoles. The `os.system` lets you run commands from within your python script

As well you can go to the `Terminal` tab and run `python home_scorer_macro.py`

[image: PyCharm tabs]

Comment: exactly, this is what I want to execute: python home_scorer_macro.py , but it showed an error

Comment: OK just go to the terminal tab in PyCharm then and run `python home_scorer_macro.py`

Comment: Yes, i see that. I said to run it in the *terminal* tab though. You are stating you ran it in the *Python Console* tab.

Comment: I don't have it in my pycharm version? is it because I use windows?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm on Windows with the community version of PyCharm. I'll post my tabs in my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188123/discussion-between-reedinationer-and-ghanem).

Comment: ah ok, maybe because I use the Educational version .. Now I found it.

Comment: "One" of the  solution has posted in the post's comments,  using Run command